# How to display the abstract with javascript

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I have a page that is a list of items, where I show the article title, author and abstract, but I want to show the abstract with javascript, a link that says show abstract and when I click out the absract od this article.[image: Example-1]

Then when clicking on the same link that hide the abstract.

[image: Example-2. Hiding the abstract]

Any idea to do this.
PS: I am using the latest version of Drupal 7.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided, as defined in [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I´ve implemented a module which is in review process and provides jquery ui formatters for fields. May be it helps you. https://drupal.org/sandbox/Enxebre/2097961 https://drupal.org/node/2098029

Comment: I can download this module??

Comment: Sure, but becouse it is a sandbox module yet, you can download it in this way: "git clone --branch 7.x-1.x http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/Enxebre/2097961.git jqueryui_formatters" If I am understanding you, you can achieve the expected behaviour choosing "accordion" as display formatter, or choosing "tabs"  and seeting "Collapsible: True"

Comment: Hi Enxebre, sorry but I don´t dowload the module, because I use windows, please help me, how to download the module?

Comment: fatal: Could not switch to 'git.drupal.org/sandbox/Enxebre': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with Field group module , ctools_collapsible theme function can also be used. As a sample code if it can help

```
print theme(
  'ctools_collapsible',
  array(
    'handle' => 'Abstract', 
    'content' => $collapsed_content, 
    'collapsed' => TRUE
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is with the [field group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module.

You can go to the display settings of your content type and add a group, set it as a div or fieldset, depending on what you want it to look like, and set it as collapsed.

That is probably the easiest way.